# Получение потоков ввода вывода другого процесса

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

Допустим мы получили пул процессов которые именуют себя `conhost`.

```
            var list = Process.GetProcessesByName("conhost").GroupBy(_x => _x.Id).ToDictionary(_x => _x.Key, _x => _x);
```

`conhost` инстанцируется для каждой копии какого либо консольного приложения Windows для предоставления потоков ввода и вывода *(Если это не так поправьте)* Так вот мне необходимо "слушать" что пишет и читает каждая консоль - как это сагрегировать я сам решу. Но проблема в том что я не могу добиться доступа к потокам ввода и вывода.

Есть предположение что это решается нативом или Winapi *(склонен больше к winapi)*.

Решение делать свой собственный дочерний процесс меня не устраивает. Мне необходимо слушать пул процессов. А точнее получить доступ к их потокам ввода и вывода.

Comment: У Интела вроде есть свой очень качественный IPC, я забыл названия, попробуйте погуглить. Но я как бы не очень понял, вам нужно из одного процесса получать IO всех экземпляров? Это ведь пример обычного IPC, а из существует уже довольно много реализаций.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов каждый раз при запуске консольного приложения сама Windows инстанцирует процесс conhost. сколько консольных приложений столько и conhos'ов. мне необходимо слушать каждый conhost - поток ввода и вывода.

Comment: Почему нельзя реализовывать межпроцессное взаимодействие?

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов потому что я хочу слушать консоли, а не свои приложения, я хочу например запустить cmd.exe ввести туда echo hello и получить оттуда hello, и видеть у себя что такой то conhost ввел echo hello и вывел hello. или например написал консольное приложение которое что либо вводит или выводит и смотрю что да conhost этого приложения что то вводит или выводит

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечаю на свой собственный вопрос. Всем кто интересовался этим же советую прочитать данную статью : [Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 R2: Console Host](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2009/10/05/windows-7-windows-server-2008-r2-console-host/)

По идее, ничего в мире, что невозможно решить - нет. Но решение данного вопроса ведет в сторону хака, что конечно же нельзя обсуждать на stackoverflow.

Comment: Хаки можно обсуждать на SO. Если они не являются зловредными.